# How can I get my XPS1330 fan to work?

Tags: 11.10, dell, fan, xps

Just upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 and now my laptop's fan is not working- my computer gets really warm. I can still run it for about an hour before it gets really hot and I shut it off out of fear that it will fry.

I've been referred to this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/InstallingUbuntuOnADellXPSM1330 but honestly I am new and don't know how to get powertop to work.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!